# How do I configure a resource filter in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I tried [following the instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-97.htm), but there's no "Resources Filters" section on the Resources property page.  How do I configure the resource filters?  I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that you give is for Helios (3.6), not Galileo (3.5.x). The functionality you seek does not exist in Galileo.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-97.htm

Comment: That's strange, because Eclipse isn't telling me there's an update available.  How do I upgrade?

Comment: To upgrade, you'll need to install helios and then install all of your plugins again. There isn't really a nice upgrade path.